# I need to detect the user's active browser extensions / add-ons

Tags: vimeo, browser-addons

I don't want my website user to download my protected Vimeo videos - there is a couple of extensions that can download the video regardless of what I do.

How can I detect if the user is using them and redirect that page to somewhere else.

Comment: Think about how stupid (and dangerous) it would be if your browser told every website which extensions were installed. So, this is plain impossible. Your Video is just a file. A file that the browser needs to play the video. The file needs to get from Vimeo's server to the user somehow. And as soon as they get it, they can just save it. That's how it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know the extensions the user have. As [Mozilla said](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/889811):

> You can't check for extensions that are installed. Plugins can be
>   detected via navigator.plugins as you posted, but you can't detect
>   extensions for privacy and security reasons.

As a general rule, if it's on the Internet, users will be able to copy the content. You can make the content *harder* to copy, but it's almost impossible to come up with a perfect solution.